# In the flip function my character's gun is pointing elsewhere. I want it to look at the position of my mouse

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

My weapon object is my character's child object and so when my character turns, my weapon object is facing where my character is facing. What I want is that my weapon object can move in a different way than my character. When I give my character the flip function, my weapon object doesn't look at my mouse position because it turns to where my character is looking. I tried to explain this situation with images below. Can you help me with this issue?

[image]

[image]

the code structure of my character is like this

```
    private void Update()
    {
        if (isDashing)
        {
            return;
        }

        //Player Movement

        float moveX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float moveY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        moveDirection = new Vector2(moveX, moveY).normalized;

        if (moveDirection.x != 0 || moveDirection.y != 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        }


        if (moveDirection.x < 0 && facingRight == true)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        if (moveDirection.x > 0 && facingRight == false)
        {
            Flip();
        }



        // Mouse Position
        displacement = weapon.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(displacement.y, displacement.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        weapon.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle + 180);

        Vector3 aimLocationScale = Vector3.one;
        if (angle > 90 || angle < -90)
        {
            aimLocationScale.y = 1f;
        } else
        {
            aimLocationScale.y = -1f;
        }
        weapon.localScale = aimLocationScale;


        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && canDash)
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("isDashing");
            StartCoroutine(Dash());
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            if (Time.time > nextShotTime)
            {
                GunWeapon.SetActive(true);
                nextShotTime = Time.time + timeBetweenShots;
                Instantiate(projectile, shotPoint.position, shotPoint.rotation);
            }
            StartCoroutine(PutGun());

        }

        Attack();
    }

    void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
        Scaler.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = Scaler;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isDashing)
        {
            return;
        }
        Move();


    }


    void Move()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDirection.x * speed, moveDirection.y * speed);
    }




    void Attack()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !isAttacking)
        {
            isAttacking = true;
            GunWeapon.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Dash()
    {
        canDash = false;
        isDashing = true;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDirection.x * dashSpeed, moveDirection.y * dashSpeed);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashDuration);
        isDashing = false;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashCooldown);
        canDash = true;
    }

    private IEnumerator PutGun()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(putinWeaponTime);
        GunWeapon.SetActive(false);

    }

}
```

Comment: Please help me guys